# Prevent XSS in Symfony

Tags: javascript, symfony, xss

How can I prevent XSS when I show data from a textarea with a wyswyg editor in Symfony2?

I have a textarea with tinyMCE editor. I can insert code for bold, italic, and after I can show the data in the browser with the twig filter raw:

```
{{miArticulo.contenido|raw}}
```

But when I write script in the textarea, for example, an alert, it is rendered in the browser too;

How Can I show only secure metas from HTML? I try surround with the twig filter autoescape, but I failed:

```
{% autoescape 'html' %}{{miArticulo.contenido|raw}}{% endautoescape %}
```

Can I show secure content con twig or I should try with other libraries such as HTMLPurifier

Comment: What about `{{miArticulo.contenido|escape('html')|raw}}`? Isn't that available in Symphony2? http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/escape.html

Comment: I try it and all html is escaped, I would escape only insecure labels, such as <script>

Comment: Did you also try `escape('js')`?

Comment: Yes, I try it and I get stranger output such as: `\x3Cp\x3E\x3Cstrong\x3`

Comment: I am unable to find more information on the `js` escape strategy implemented in twig. Could be a bug. I think your best bet becomes implementing your own custom escape strategy. http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/escape.html#custom-escapers

Comment: I will try it or move to HTMLPurifierBundle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases like this I am using this bundle:

https://github.com/Exercise/HTMLPurifierBundle

probably best performance you will get using it on the form when user sends HTML. (via form data transformer as described in docs)

No other option as far as I know will prevent it for all clever ways to put js in html.

Answer (score 4):

Besides using a templating engine like Twig, I highly suggest to implement the [Content Security Policy](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/) nonce headers.

```
header('Content-Security-Policy', 'script-src 'nonce-randomNonceString' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 'strict-dynamic' https: http:; object-src 'none');
```

**They forbid running other scripts than those explicitly whitelisted.** A downside is that you need to add a randomly generated *nonce* argument to each `<script>` tag in your code.

I wrote a detailed [tutorial how to implement CSP 3 with nonce in Symfony](http://blog.ikvasnica.com/entry/how-to-protect-php-application-from-xss-attacks-csp-3-nonce#nonce-symfony), so the nonce argument is generated automatically per each request. Feel free to use the solution.